# React Single Page

Tags: reactjs, web

I have a component for the content of my page... It is the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/content.css';
import Home from './home';

const Content = ()=>{
    return(
        <div className='contain-content'>
            <Home/>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Content;
```

and I have another component menu with some divs containing "Buttons":

```
const IcoMenu = () => {
  return (
    <div className="menu-contain" >
      <div id="home" className="ico-menu">...</div>
      <div id="resume" className="ico-menu">...</div>
    </div>
  );
 }
```

I'm really new to React and what I want to achieve is that when I click a button, it updates the Content component... and changes the Home component to another one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../styles/content.css';
import Home from './home';
import OtherComponent from './otherComponent';
import IcoMenu from './IcoMenu';

const Content = () => {    
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState('home');

  const renderPage = () => {
    if (currentPage === 'home') {
      return <Home />;
    } else if (currentPage === 'other') {
      return <OtherComponent />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='contain-content'>
      <IcoMenu setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}/>
      {renderPage()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

you can pass a function to each button in the IcoMenu component that updates the Content component's state when clicked:

```
const IcoMenu = ({setCurrentPage}) => {
  const handleClick = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <div className="menu-contain" >
      <div id="home" className="ico-menu" onClick={() => handleClick('home')}>
        ...
      </div>
      <div id="other" className="ico-menu" onClick={() => handleClick('other')}>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried your proposal but in the "Content" component it is returning the "Aside", not the Home component... Although the console does detect them when they are pressed... By the way the "Content" component is independent of the "icoMenu"